# Basic file structure misunderstanding

Tags: angular

So, I have an app folder where both my component and its underlying template are held. My question is, in a string in component where I specify the location of my template in @Component decorator, eg.

```
@Component({
    selector: "add-site-view",
    templateUrl:"app/add-site.template.html"
})
```

, why do I need to specify explicitly "app/template.html" and cannot use "./" instead of "app/"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Component` URLs (`templateUrl` and `styleUrls`) are resolved relative to `index.html`, and not the the `.ts` file.
That is why you have to specify the full path (starting from `index.html`).

What you can do is use the official `angular-cli` at https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

They use Webpack and basically `@Component` URLs are relative to the `.ts` file, if that is what you need.

Comment: Cool, I understand now. Thanks! I did use cli all the time, but wanted to toy around with building everything by hand!